# SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate on PHP 7.1 Ubuntu 16.04 NGINX

Tags: php, ssl, curl, nginx, wsdl

I'm trying to consume a service over HTTPS through cURL.

When I exec the following command in CLI it works fine.

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction: createLabel" --data @testRequest.xml https://labelqa.estafeta.com/EstafetaLabel20/services/EstafetaLabelWS?wsdl --cacert labelqa.estafeta.com.pem
```

But when I try to use the same but in PHP, the browser returns me this error.

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I have the following code.

```
$ch = curl_init("https://labelqa.estafeta.com/EstafetaLabel20/services/EstafetaLabelWS?wsdl");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "xmlRequest=testRequest.xml");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
    'SOAPAction: createLabel',
]);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'labelqa.estafeta.com.crt');

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (FALSE === $response)
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));

curl_close($ch);

print_r($response);

die;
```

The call should be made with PHP's SoapClient but it does not work anyway because of the same problem.

You can get de **labelqa.estafeta.com.crt** cert downloading it from this link https://labelqa.estafeta.com/EstafetaLabel20/services/EstafetaLabelWS?wsdl.

Comment: That link sure doesn't look like it leads to anything cacert-file-y...

Comment: You can put that link in your browser and when the browser warn you about the ssl connection you can download the certificate. http://docs.bvstools.com/home/ssl-documentation/exporting-certificate-authorities-cas-from-a-website